# qt creator 3.6 (build from source) cannot start process qmake when build any qt app project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have built qt creator 3.6 from source (from [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/tree/3.6)) with no error. Everything is OK except when I create a Qt Application project in the qt creator I built, it cannot qmake my .pro file. 
The error is :

```
Cannot start process "C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\rick\Desktop\Temp\SvTest6\SvTest6.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2015 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
Error while building/deploying project SvTest6 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 32bit)
When executing step "qmake"
20:26:29: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

If I execute the command:

```
"C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\rick\Desktop\Temp\SvTest6\SvTest6.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2015 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
```

in windows cmd.exe, everything is OK.

Could you guys give me some hint about this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify qmake arguments separately:
[image]

and not inside the "Command" field.